# Assign filtered data to controller variable in ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I want to assign filtered data to controller variable in ng-if:

```
<section ng-if="($ctrl.filteredOperations = $ctrl.operations | filter: customFilter).length > 0">
    <header>Count: {{$ctrl.filteredOperations .length}}</header>
    <div ng-repeat="operation in $ctrl.filteredOperations ">...</div>
</section>
```

I tried different approaches with no luck.

**UPDATE**

Why am I doing this?

I have a service which holds the collection of operations.

financialService.operations(); - this returns operations, from API or from cache.

So in my controller:

```
financialService.operations().then(function(ops){
    vm.operations = ops;
});
```

Now if I update my cache by any means, it'll update my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to move the filtering to your controller:

```
$ctrl.filteredOperations = $filter('customFilter')($ctrl.operations);
```

And then display it as the following:

```
<section ng-if="$ctrl.filteredOperations.length">
    <header>Count: {{$ctrl.filteredOperations.length}}</header>
    <div ng-repeat="operation in $ctrl.filteredOperations">...</div>
</section>
```

---

In my opinion, when the logic become complex, it is always better to move it to controller instead of doing all in HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it'll be a lot easier. But I want to bind by reference to source. In my case, `$ctrl.operations` - is a source reference. I want a deep watch over filtered data.

Comment: @Kindzoku Say what?

Comment: Don't know how to react on "Say what" actually. Let's pretend that we forgot about my initial question and debate about this answer. Lets start from other end. What if any operation property could be changed. How should I change the view in this case? If i'll assign variable in controller, than `$ctrl.filteredOperations` will hold a copy of collection. And any changes maded to data source in service won't chande `$ctrl.filteredOperations`.